# Graph not properly rendered in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have the following data in data.dat file .

```
TA   | OP
```

---

```
6    | 20
17   | 24
18   | 17
19   | 17
22   | 19
33   | 27
19   | 28
13   | 18
24   | 16
19   | 19
9    | 18
21   | 22
16   | 10
19   | 12
22   | 19
26   | 19
27   | 19
11   | 11
25   | 16
15   | 17
24   | 22
24   | 17
21   | 20
```

Here TA means Traditional approach and OP means Our Approach . I have to show a relation between these two columns . For this purpose I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]

  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{40}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{40}

  % grid
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=1, xstep=1] (\xmin,\ymin) grid
  (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[above] {$y$};

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,40}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {1,2,3,...,40}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};

  % plot the data from the file data.dat
  % smooth the curve and mark the data point with a dot
  \draw[color=blue] plot[smooth,mark=*,mark size=1pt] file {data.dat}
   node [right] {data};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But surprisingly I have got the following picture:

[image]

Why ? What Have I to do to get the right relationship ?

The graph that shows the relationship between two column is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question quite heavily: what you are after is plotting data against the implicit row number in a table. That doesn't come across at all in the description: it's only the final figure that gives it away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your data is not sorted so TikZ goes back and forth to draw the points. I would really recommend `pgfplots` for this. I've sorted your table and plotted again

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%<- Loads pgfplots anyway
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{data.dat}\mytable
\pgfplotstablesort{\mysortedtable}{\mytable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=40,ymin=0,ymax=40,grid=both]
\addplot+[smooth,mark size=1pt] table {\mysortedtable}  node [right] {data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice at 19,22 and 24 you have more than one sample per x.

What you say as *a relation* is really confusing but if you have the data file without the `|` rule character, you can do the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%<- Loads pgfplots anyway
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotstableread[]{data.dat}\mytable


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=25,ymin=0,ymax=40,grid=both]
\addplot+[smooth,mark size=1pt] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=TA] {\mytable};
\addplot+[smooth,mark size=1pt] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=OP] {\mytable};
\legend{Traditional Approach, Our Approach}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are here only one curve in this graph ? I have to show relationship between the two column . So there should be two column

Comment: @user54714 Two columns with respect to what?

Comment: between each other .

Comment: @user54714 And this is between each other. x is first y is second column, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Typical: I was half-way though writing an answer using `\coordindex` for the implicit row number :-)

Comment: Very nice and clean answer.

Answer (score 4):

Would this be what you try to achieve? Here the plot options `ybar` with filled blue colors is used. There are many options you could try, say, `sharp plot, only marks, const plot, const plot mark left, ycomb` etc. But in this case, `ybar` and `only marks` are probably better choices, IMHO, for clarity.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm]

  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{40}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{40}

  % grid
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=1, xstep=1]   (\xmin,\ymin) grid
  (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[above] {$y$};

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,40}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {1,2,3,...,40}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};

  % plot the data from the file data.dat
  % smooth the curve and mark the data point with a dot
  \draw[color=blue,fill] plot[smooth,mark=*,mark size=1pt, ybar] file {data.dat};  
  \node [color=blue] at (22,24)  {data};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```